# Tab's tag text overlaps search placeholder

Tags: bug, search

When I click on a tab from the index page, the search box displays the tag the actual tab is representing, however, it does not obscure the placeholder text of the field.

The placeholder disappears on hover.

I am using Safari 12603.1.30.0.34 on macOS 10.12.4.

[image: obscured search placeholder]

Comment: Seems like it's fixed now. Nice!